# Use AdMob on Xamarin Studio with Android, Google Play Services don't exist

Tags: android, xamarin, admob, google-play-services, xamarin-studio

I tried recently to try to use Google AdMob on my Xamarin Android application. However, I have not been able to succeed. First of all, I'm not able to follow tutorials, (for instance, this one: https://blog.tommyparnell.com/admob-with-xamarin-part-1-banner-ads/), here it is saying to go to "get more components" (I'm using Xamarin Studio) and download Google Play Services (Jellybean). However, I'm not able to find it, instead I find a lot of Google Play Services components. I have tried to install the one called: "Google Play Services - Ads" ( I imagine that this one is the one related with Admobs). However, seems that something is not working, the component appears like inactivated and it is saying the following:

```
Some required packages are not referenced by the project
```

I'm quite desperate and really don't know how to proceed. What can I do?
Also note that I have the latest version of the SDK. Could be that the problem? If so, how can I fix the thing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial that you referred to is *out-dated* and is using the deprecated version of the "Xamarin Google Play Services - All" package.

You want the individual **"Ads"** package that will provide the `ADMob` namespace (`using ADMob;`) that will also install the related Play Service dependencies and you have to update the code accordingly from the tutorial to match the new Ads namespace/api. The overall code and process presented for showing ads is valid.

**Open the Package Manager and search for "Xamarin Google Play Services Ads"**

```
>Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads -Version 27.0.0
```

[image]

**Nuget Page:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads/27.0.0

**Latest Beta Version:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads/28.0.0-beta1

> The 'Xamarin Google Play Services - All' nuget package is now
>   deprecated.
>
> You should instead use the individual NuGet packages to get only the
>   bindings you need in your application.
>
> You can find the individual packages by searching for 'xamarin google
>   play services':
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xamarin+google+play+services

Comment: does this also work on devices where no google play services are installed?

Comment: @smedasn The `Ads` version does, the `Ads.Lite` does not. So if you are submitting to the Google Play Store, you can use the "Lite" version as only devices that have Play services installed would work anyway, otherwise use the full version that includes the Play services that are required for Ads to work. Re: `"Google Mobile Ads SDK implementation in the Google Play services APK is also included in the Google Play services client library. This allows for support on devices without the Google Play services APK"` : https://developers.google.com/admob/android/lite-sdk